Mui Slider - custom marks

Hi All,
I have come across this issue with Mui Slider and its marks. If you look at the screenshot, i would like to add some padding/margin (i.e. 8px) to first marker (white dot) and same for the last marker.
at the moment i have this:
[`& :nth-child(1 of .${sliderClasses.mark})`]: {
   left: '2% !important',
},
[`& .${sliderClasses.mark}:nth-last-child(1 of .${sliderClasses.mark})`]: {
   left: '98% !important',
},

this works, but it seems little bit cumbersome and surely it can be done bit better.
Any idea or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated ;-)

How about adding the length of the slider so the dots' position will be the same, but there will be some padding on both sides.
Example:
.css-3ndvyc {
    width: calc(100% + 16px);
    left: -8px;
}
.MuiSlider-track.css-10opxo5 {
    left: -8px !important;
}

-- Note: Sorry I can't comment because my point is too low, I tried this method by editing the slider css on https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/
